# What to say when running into someone?

Tags: conversation

Well, I am an Asian who study English as a second language. My question arose because I wanted to translate from my own language. Suppose that I am pondering while walking on the street that I want to see someone, and suddenly I run into that someone. I think I might say something that translate to "Oh! I am wanting to see you. Such a nice timing!"

May I ask a few questions as follows:

1. Among English speakers, is it usual to say it like this?
2. Are there other alternatives which are more common.
3. I guess "I've wanted to see you?" is OK too? I guess from the meaning of other usage I've found [on this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331840/have-wanted-to-do-have-been-wanting-to-do).

Comment: "Oh, I was hoping to see you."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've run into the person, you can shift your desire to the past. So, instead of saying:

> Oh! I have wanted to see you!

you could say:

> Oh! I **was** wanting to see you.

Or you can use the version suggested by Davo:

> Oh, I was **hoping** to see you.

I don't think your original version is ungrammatical, but it doesn't sound as natural to my native ear.

---

As for the second half, *timing* does not take an indefinite article. So, it wouldn't be:

> Such a nice timing!

but, rather:

> Such nice timing!

As for alternate possibilities, one way you could reword that timing part would be:

> Oh, I was hoping I'd run into you. What a coincidence!

Comment: For reasons which aren't immediately clear to me, native Anglophones (IE speakers excepted) rarely use the continuous past form with ***was wanting*** today - but there's no such constraint with similar verbs such as ***was expecting, was hoping,*** etc., as implied by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+wanting+to%2CI+was+hoping+to%2CI+was+expecting+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20wanting%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20hoping%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20expecting%20to%3B%2Cc0).